# Postgres- merge 2 different query results

Tags: join, union, postgresql-9.5

I have 3 tables table1,table2,maintable:

table1

| tb1col1 | tb1col2 | maintable_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | John | 123 |
| dof | Mat | 123 |
| cda | Mary | 123 |
| xyz | Max | 687 |

table2

| tb2col1 | tb2col2 | maintable_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2.0 | 123 |
| B | 5.0 | 123 |
| C | 11.0 | 345 |
| A | 2.0 | 687 |

maintable

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2023-09-10 |
| 345 | 2023-09-11 |

I want to merge 2 queries with below result :

| tb1col1 | tb1col2 | tb2col1 | tb2col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | John | A | 2.0 |
| dof | Mat | B | 5.0 |
| cda | Mary |  |  |

Ive tried
select *  from (select tb1col1,tb1col2 from maintable m  left join table1 tb1 on tb1.maintable_id=m.id where date='2023-09-10')y full join (select tb2col1,tb2col2 from maintable m left join table2 tb2 on tb2.maintable_id=m.id where date='2023-09-10')x on y.maintable_id=x.maintable_id;

which gives me:

| tb1col1 | tb1col2 | tb2col1 | tb2col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | John | A | 2.0 |
| abc | John | B | 5.0 |
| dof | Mat | A | 2.0 |
| dof | Mat | B | 5.0 |
| cda | Mary | A | 2.0 |
| cda | Mary | B | 5.0 |

Ive also tried UNION

(select tb1col1,tb1col2,NULL as tb2col1,NULL as tb2col2 from maintable m  left join table1 tb1 on (tb1.maintable_id=m.id) union all (select NULL as tb1col1,NULL as tb1col2,tb2col1,tb2col2 from maintable m left join table2 tb2 on tb2.maintable_id=m.id);

which gives me :

| tb1col1 | tb1col2 | tb2col1 | tb2col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | John |  |  |
| dof | Mat |  |  |
| cda | Mary |  |  |
|  | A | 2.0 |  |
|  | B | 5.0 |  |

But expected result is

| tb1col1 | tb1col2 | tb2col1 | tb2col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | John | A | 2.0 |
| dof | Mat | B | 5.0 |
| cda | Mary |  |  |

Comment: Did you use [tag:postgresql-9.5] intentionally? That version is pretty outdated

Comment: postgres 9.5 is used in my test server. We have not upgraded